# Check if the page is the front page in a template

Tags: 7

How do I make a simple front page check wich only shows a  in my template when the user is on the front page of the drupal website?

I tried this but it ended up crashing:

```
<?php function drupal_is_front_page() {?> <h1>TEST</h1> <?php } ?>
```

Is this possible with a if instead of this function wich i found on the drupal website?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should not declare a function in a Drupal template. Instead, you should just refer to that function:

```
<?php
if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    ?><h1>Test</h1><?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Note that if your template is a derivative of page.tpl.php you already have the `$is_front` variable available

Answer (score 6):

`drupal_is_front_page()` returns boolean value.

```
<?php if(drupal_is_front_page()): ?>
<h1>TEST</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```